# Add a button on the NestedList toolbar (right aligned)

Tags: sencha-touch-2, toolbar, nested-lists, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm trying to add a button (right aligned) on the toolbar of a nestedlist. Here is my code :

```
Ext.define('Test.view.NestedList', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',

requires: ['Ext.dataview.NestedList'],

xtype: 'mynestedlist',

config: {
    modal: true,
    centered: true,
    layout:'fit',
    width:'80%',
    height:'80%',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'nestedlist',
        fullscreen: true,
        title: 'Groceries',
        displayField: 'text',
        store: 'MyTreeStore',
        initialize: function(){
                console.log("Add the button on the toolbar");
                this.getToolbar().add({xtype: 'spacer'});
                this.getToolbar().add({xtype: 'button', iconCls: 'compose', ui: 'plain', action: ''});                  
            }
    }]

}
});
```

The button does not align to the right of the toolbar but appears to the left.
Does anyone have an idea to make this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is try adding a `titlebar` to your nestedlist and then align the button `right`.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I just would like to have one "toolbar" at the top, not 2.